# How to generate .so file and the corresponding Java interface in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

I want to generate a SO file and its corresponding Java interface for using it into another project.

**What I have done so far:**

I have created a project in Android Studio 2.3.3 (the latest version of 2017-08-09) with 'Include C++ support' and wrote some C/C++ code and compile it and when I run the program it was successfully called and returned a "Hello from JNI" string.

So after that, I looked the output for the generated `.so` file, but there I did not find this file. After that, I found the generated APK file in the output folder and when I **extracted** it, inside I found these folders which all contain `.so` file:

- arm64-v8a
- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- mips
- mips64
- x86
- x86_64

Now the question is, how can I use these `.so` files into another project, because of this I searched a lot on the internet, but unfortunately, I did not find any solution, the solution that they mentioned all was to create a folder in the `main` folder of the project name it `jniLibs` and after modify the Gradle file and so ..., but no one was working.

Here I want to know that how can we add the .so file and the corresponding Java interface to use them in the project?

It is the error that now I get to the new project when trying to call the JNI function in the .so file.

[image]

Comment: You want to know the procedure for CMake build right?

Comment: @KavachChandra I just want to work this out, I don't know how to link these files in the new project, and also how to generate the .so file and the corresponding Java interface. These .so files I have found them in the extracted APK, which I think cannot be like this, it may have better way to generate and reuse in the other projects

Comment: What is the package name for the native String getHello in your second app? Does it match your first working app?

Comment: Yes, it matches, it has exactly the same package name which is the first project.

Comment: did you include the library also in the java     `static {
        System.loadLibrary( "yourlib");
    }`

Comment: Yeah, definitely, I have done all things that are needed.

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753112/how-do-i-use-jni-with-aar-library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. *I don't know if it is the good way to solve.*

When you created a project with 'Include C++ Support'and wrote the Native (C/C++) code, then you run the app, if everything works well, then you can look to the generated .so files in the build folder in the following path: Open it and you will see the .so files for all the platforms in separate folders.

[image]

So now create a new project and change the project view to 'Project' perspective:

[image]

And copy and paste all the folders in libs folder of the 'app':

[image]

And then add the following code in the Gradle file:

```
task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: "create a jar archive of the native libs") {
    destinationDir file("$projectDir/libs")
    baseName "Native_Libs"
    extension "jar"
    from fileTree(dir: "libs", include: "**/*.so")
    into "lib"
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

After adding code the Gradle file looks like this:

[image]

After it done, sync the Gradle file:

[image]

And make the project from the Build menu:

[image]

After the process has been done, change the project view to Android, and you will see a 'jniLibs' folder and the generated .jar file inside this:

[image]

Now go to create a new project and do nothing just copy and paste the .jar file in the libs folder:

[image]

And now right click and select the 'Add As Library':

[image]

And select 'Native Library Location' and click on OK and also in the next dialog click again the OK.

[image]

And now create the same class in the same package as you wrote the C/C++ code in the first project. And load the lib by calling like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
```

**And after that, the IDE, will give an error on the native method, do not care and do your work.**

**Note:** *The native method class must be the same name and in the same package as it was created, otherwise the method cannot be found.*

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem with JNI.

Comment: this will work, however you will need the same package name and this much work when you need to port your library. These solutions are all choice of flavors.

Comment: Hmm yes, it looks lot of steps, but when you created the jar file, then you can easily use it in the next projects without any further steps.

Comment: If you will not frequently change the project that creates the .so files and will always have the same package name then this great.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil hello how to update '.so' file in android studio? 
It is already included in one of the projects but now I need to update that file in AS

Answer (score 2):

These .so files are in separate folders as different devices have different architectures, and linking a so that is incompatible will cause failures.
[How to find ARM processor version on android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630386/how-to-find-arm-processor-version-on-android-device) shows how to get android architecture using terminal (Also there is a internal api for Java).

1. You can make your JNI project as an android library / module so that you can integrate it easily to other projects. You will need to write a wrapper. Most of the 3rd party libraries use this kind of approach.
2. You can create another C++ project and then copy the build folders into new project lib folder. Then you will need to add these library dependencies in CMakeLists.txt. However you will still have to make a jni interface that will call your library. In CMakeLists you will need to include using

`include_directories(path_to_your_include)
 add_library( lib_yourlib SHARED IMPORTED )
 set_target_properties(lib_yourlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION              path_to_your_abi_folders/${ANDROID_ABI}/yourlib.so)`

GitHub project that showcases the first approach
https://github.com/khedd/SimpleAndroidModule

Comment: I am wondering why such a simple job, the Android Studio made it such complex. It must be very very easy because almost every one developing Android apps will need this.

Comment: If there is I currently do not know, however I am fine with the first way modules are real life/time savers.

Comment: Hmm... I will try your suggested ways if it was working.

Comment: Look to my answer

Comment: i have .so file of other app that i have decompile i don't have native-lib.cpp file of that .so means i don't have native code i only have .so can i integrate and run it in my project because when i m runing the project this error is coming java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int com.krunal.camarademo.Libs.nativesystem.DMDHDR.getBracketedCount() (tried Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount and Java_com_krunal_camarademo_Libs_nativesystem_DMDHDR_getBracketedCount__)